# Pipe bc calculator output back to parent fork()

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to get the program to take input from the initial console. Take the arguments and send them to a child fork, run the bc calculator on the data, then return the finished value back to the parent.

I want a user to enter `echo "11*13" | ./mycalc`

And get the response of: `143`

**mycalc.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int p[2];
        int r[2];
        pipe(p);
        pipe(r);

        pid_t childId = fork();

        if(childId == -1)
        {
                perror("Failed to fork");
                return -1;
        }

        if ( childId == 0)
        {
                printf("Child Process Has Run\n");
                close(p[1]);
                close(r[0]);
                dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(r[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                execlp("bc", "bc", NULL);
        } else {
                printf("Parent process has run\n");
                close(p[0]);
                close(r[1]);
                write(p[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

                char data[128];
                int len = read(r[0], data, 13);
                if (len < 0) {
                      perror("Error reading from child");
                }
                printf("The data is %s", data);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

When I run it I get

```
Parent process has run
Child Process Has Run
```

and the cursor just sits there like it is waiting for input, but no matter what I type it does nothing.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: Your proposed command line is `echo "11*13" | ./mycalc`, but your code writes `argv[1]` to `bc` — and there isn't an `argv[1]` in that command line. Make your mind up time: either read standard input and send that to `bc` or expect an argument ``./mycalc "11*13"`` and send the argument.  Consider having the parent wait until the child completes. Do add error reporting and exit immediately after the `execlp()`. There's no need to check whether it failed: if it returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it doesn't return. Your parent reports failure unconditionally — that's a tad pessimistic, isn't it?

Comment: You also need to close the write end of the pipe to the child (`bc`) when you're done.  `bc` is waiting for something more interesting from you before it sends anything.  Closing the pipe will tell it that there is no more input and it will exit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I had was the pipes not being properly closed. After I make sure the pipes closed I was able to continue.

Comment: I got it to work, this was not the finished code I ended with as I added much more, so hopefully there are not more errors in this code. But if there are, the issue at hand was closing the pipe in the child so it would end the process and the parent would resume. After I did that, yes it worked.

Comment: It is quite useless to do anything after a call to an exec... family function, because it normally doesn't return. So if you think your added calls to `close` after `exec` make a difference, you are mistaken. The child never executes them.

Comment: I updated the response. The purpose of the answer was to let anyone know what the issue was, which was the pipes not being properly closed. 

The code I have is nothing close to when I asked the question and I did not think it would help. The code may have been flawed still and not working, so I removed the code and explained the problem I had.

Comment: The updated answer explains nothing at all. Which pipes need to be closed and at which point?

Comment: It was a question that no one answered. I was trying to add a little extra context to help since no one else was answering. It was either explaining I fixed it by properly closing the pipes, or leave it unanswered since I no longer have the working code. Maybe I should have just left the question blank and not tried.. but at least I tried to help!

Comment: Your answer isn't helpful. You can delete your question or leave it unanswered.

Comment: Unfortunately when I deleted a message was what I got in trouble for and told I needed to also answer my questions and not have them unanswered. So I came back and answered because I got in trouble for doing what you suggested. I have noted your concern and I will try and find time to come and create a better response. Thank you for your concern!